# How to make overflow tabs as dropdown in bootstrap using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to build an responsive admin panel in which selected content will be shown as New Tab, I am trying to make tabs to go under drop down menu when tab overflows.

My `<body>` is divided into two panels (left and right). In Left panel, I have kept all files and folder list. Whenever user clicked on any file then that file contents will be shown on right panel as new tab.

When more tabs are opened then tabs which are overflow in right panel then those tabs should move under dropdown menu. I am looking for a method supporting jQuery and bootstrap.

Comment: can you create the problem with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tab's bootstrap

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>

$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('active')){
        $( $(this).attr('href') ).hide();
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
});
```

[this menu accordion](http://www.bootply.com/uBoT3zP1P2)

this a show content left to right

```
$('#left .folder').click(function(){
    //$('#right .item').text($(this).text());
    $('#right .item').text('some text');
})
```